# Does (or has) the US military launch anything besides weapons and weapons tests into space themselves?

Tags: launch, military

Discussion below [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29843/12102) has lead to this question.

I'd like to know if the US military has in the past, or still does, launch non-weapon payloads into orbit themselves. (*Orbit*, as opposed to small sounding rockets for science)

As far as I know they currently use commercial launch providers to put military satellites into space (thus the other question) but have they launched things to orbit themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could have a discussion about what "non weapon" means but the military has launched numerous research payloads on ICBM type boosters.

Some examples

Gemini-B, a test vehicle for the planned military space station [Manned Orbiting Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Orbiting_Laboratory).  The Gemini flew a suborbital trajectory to test if it was OK to cut a hatch in its heat shield (it was) but the MOL mockup continued into orbit.

[image]

[ASSET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASSET_(spacecraft)) a maneuverable reentry vehicle (ok, it's suborbital, but not a sounding rocket, and very cool)

[image]

Comment: I need to sign off for a few hours, but not before asking the following. Feel free to edit if necessary: [What is the “baby rocket” attached to the booster on this rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29850/12102)

Comment: It's a duplicate! See you later.

Answer (score 4):

The USAF has a long history of launching space missions. US military satellites are launched not by NASA, but by the air force.
This includes for example:

- spy satellites
- military communications sats
- GPS

[USAF Space Command](https://www.afspc.af.mil/) has the following mission:

> to "Provide resilient and affordable Space and Cyberspace capabilities for the Joint Force and the Nation."[9] As a result, AFSPC's activities make the space domain reliable to United States warfighters (i.e., combat forces personnel) by assuring their access to space.
>
> AFSPC's primary mission areas are:
>
> - Space forces support, involving the launching of satellites and other high-value payloads into space using a variety of expendable launch vehicles and operating those satellites once in space
> - Space control, ensuring the friendly use of space through the conduct of counterspace operations encompassing surveillance, negation, protection and space intelligence analysis[10]
> - Force enhancement, providing satellite-based weather, communications, intelligence, missile warning, and navigation; force enhancement is direct support to the warfighter

[Before NASA was formed](https://history.nasa.gov/40thann/define.htm), the USAF was already working on space capability (along with their ICBM program). Many early launches were done by the USAF, with rockets derived from ICBMs.

There's an [Air Force station](https://www.nasa.gov/content/cape-canaveral-air-force-station/) at Cape Canaveral. Launch support (range monitoring, communications, launch abort etc.) for NASA missions is done by the USAF.