# What is the "baby rocket" attached to the booster on this rocket?

Tags: rockets, identify-this-object

@OrganicMarble's [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8eQx.jpg) shows some very cool looking historical rocket launches.

What is the smaller structure attached to the booster on the right side, that looks like a "baby rocket"?

[image]

Comment: @OrganicMarble I see. I've voted to close as well, thanks!

Comment: @OrganicMarble is this similar to some of the things shown here? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20755/how-does-a-single-srb-control-attitude/20763#20763 oh, I mean in this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20763/12102

Comment: It is indeed, and I mentioned it in my answer to that duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the tanks for the "fluid thrust vector control" (TVC) system.  There's one on each booster.

[image]

(from [NASA SX-79](https://www.scribd.com/document/45970851/Titan-Centaur-NASA-s-Newest-Launch-Vehicle))  TVC would inject NO4 fluid at different points around the circumference of the nozzle to deflect the flow, which changed the thrust direction enough that a gimbeled nozzle wasn't needed.